# How to display clicked item from sidebar to first position and remaining list get hidden and on hover show the list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want sidebar menu in such a way that when I click on clients option it should remove from its position

And display to the first position and remaining menu list get hidden and show when hover on "<" icon, so how to do this using CSS and jQuery actually I don't have that much idea about front-end part.

```
<html>
<head>

<style>
.sidenav {
    width: 130px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 8px 0;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #2196F3;
    display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #064579;
}

.main {
    margin-left: 140px; */
    font-size: 28px; 
    padding: 0px 10px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>



 <script>    
    $(".main-menu li").click(function () {
  $('li', $(this).closest('ul')).not(this).hide();
      });
</scrip>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Expected output:
 when clicking on clients option it should remove and show the first option and remaining option list get hidden like this but should show on mouse hover

[image]

Above image to show remaining options in hidden and on hover show list

[image]

Now list should be on hover

[image]

Comment: Are you asking for a script that does this? You don't have anything for us to fix

Comment: You cannot expect us to write the entire code ... Even if the code doesn't work, if you were able to make any progress at all you should show us that.

Comment: Isn't it better to show that much at least? Then we don't need to start from scratch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

I updated some `css` and `Jquery` Functions

**Is It Perfect As Per Your Requirement  ?**

```js
  $(document).on('click','.sidenav a',function(){ 
            $('.sidebar').show('slow'); 
            $('.sidenav').append($('.topnav')[0].innerHTML);
            $('.topnav').empty();
            $('.topnav').append($(this)[0].outerHTML)
            $('.sidenav a').hide();
      $(this).remove()        
   });
    $('.sidebar').hover(function(){
      $('.sidenav a').show('slow');
            $(this).hide('slow')
   });
```

```css
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
 
}

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color:#2196F3;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.sidebar{
    height:20px;
    background:red;
    color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    width:5px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
}
.sidebar:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
    border:10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid red;
}
.sidenav a {
    padding: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #2196F3;
    display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #064579;
}

.main {
    margin-left: 140px; */
    font-size: 28px; 
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="topnav"></div>
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="sidebar" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: thank you so much exactly as per my expectation you did it.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(".sidenav>a").click(function () {
    $(this).siblings('a').not(this).hide();
});
$(".sidenav").find('div').hover(function(){
  $('a').css("display","block");
})
```

```css
.sidenav {
    width: 130px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 20px;
    left: 10px;
    background: #eee;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    padding: 8px 0;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #2196F3;
    display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #064579;
}

.main {
    margin-left: 140px;
    font-size: 28px; 
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="sidenav">
    <a href="#about">About</a>
    <a href="#services">Services</a>
    <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
    <div> < </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but when you mouseover the already selected item should not show in list

Answer (score 0):

**Try Following Whis includes the Css Slider**

```js
 $('.sidenav a').click(function(){
      $('.sidenav a').not(this).hide();
            $('.sidebar').show('slow');
   });
    $('.sidebar').hover(function(){
      $('.sidenav a').show('slow');
            $(this).hide('slow')
   });
```

```css
.sidebar{
    height:20px;
    background:red;
    color:#fff;
    position:relative;
    width:5px;
    text-align:center;
    line-height:40px;
}
.sidebar:after{
    content:"";
    position:absolute;
    height:0;
    width:0;
    left:100%;
    top:0;
    border:10px solid transparent;
    border-left: 5px solid red;
}
.sidenav a {
    padding: 6px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #2196F3;
    display: block;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #064579;
}

.main {
    margin-left: 140px; */
    font-size: 28px; 
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#services">Services</a>
  <a href="#clients">Clients</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
</div>
<br/>
<div class="sidebar" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but i need some different means when i click on contacts it should come upper side and when mouse over or hover in that list that item should not come again when i click on services it should come and mouseover list conain all options except contact

Comment: that mean when we click on item (i.e. Contact) then it will removed from the list?